# Significant Location Changes in IOS8

Tags: ios8, core-location

Could it be that Significant Location Updates in IOS8 requires the "Requesting Always authorization" to be called on the LocationManager? requestWhenInUseAuthorization doesn't seem to be sufficient when using SLC, even when the app is only running in the foreground. I.e., didUpdateLocation never gets called. Doesn't make any sense to me. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must request Always authorization.  This is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization) in the Discussion section under `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` which says:

> Apps cannot use any services that automatically relaunch the app, such
>   as region monitoring or the significant location change service

Signification Location Changes can launch the app when it is not in use, which requires Always permission.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought might be the problem. But it seems like a strange approach to me. Because SLC is the most power efficient way to get the users location, but requires the highest level of authorization. I think Apple are shooting themselves in their foot with this restriction.

Comment: You don't need SLC unless you want the app to be started by the system when the user isn't in the app.  If you're just monitoring location while the app is running, you can run CLLocationManager continuously with required accuracy set to 3000m to get the same battery friendly results.

Comment: I doubt that it will be as battery friendly, because it activates the GPS rather than using cellular/wifi signals. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: 3000m will turn off GPS and uses cellular/wifi only.  You don't need GPS to get 3000m accuracy.  300m or less requires GPS (GNSS).